# clearTimeout and dataset issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that changes classes on list items depending on hover time. But i get these errors in console:

```
TypeError: this.dataset is undefined
TypeError: this.clearTimeout is not a function
```

**Code:**

```
var timer = [], open = false;

$('.mainMenu li.first').hover(function() {
    if (this.dataset.timer) {
        timer.forEach(this.clearTimeout());
        clearTimeout(parseInt(this.dataset.timer));
        delete this.dataset.timer;
        open = false;
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        this.dataset.timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('open');
        delete this.dataset.timer;
        open = false;
    }, 300);
    open = true;
    } else if (open) {
    timer.push(setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).addClass('open');
    }, 300));
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('open');
    }
});
```

Html is regulat ul-li list

```
<ul>
    <li class="first"></li>
    <li class="first"></li>
    <li class="first"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you put whole javascript code where your declared `dataset` variable.

Comment: This is my whole js, its just wrapped with "$(function() {" and "});"

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, `this` in event handler refers to the DOM object. If `dataset` is a global variable and `clearTimeout` is referring to the default JavaScript function, then change `this.dataset` to `dataset` or `window.dataset` and `this.clearTimeout` to `clearTimeout` or `window.clearTimeout`.

Also, `clearTimeout` at line 5 requires an argument.